# How to generate password

Tags: random

I would like to generate a random password of a defined length which can easily be typed in with a standard keyboard.

As a start I tried the following:

```
SeedRandom["pass"];
StringJoin[RandomChoice[CharacterRange[33, 126], 10]
(* "=IP@7mbYcB" *)
```

Do you know other solutions?

Comment: "欲穷千里目，更上一层楼。"means “Yqqlm_Gs1cl”.I'm sure anyone cannot broke it.And it is easy to remember.  :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A shorter formulation equivalent to your own code is:

```
FromCharacterCode @ RandomInteger[{33, 126}, 10]
```

> ```
> "+(pCT4W#;T"
> ```

However quite a few places only accept alphanumeric passwords, and not all keyboards have the same easily accessible character sets.  If we assume that your given example is sufficiently secure you need 94^10 ~= 5*10^19 unique passwords.  This is easily accomplished by adding a single alphanumeric character as 62^11 ~= 5*10^19.  Therefore I propose:

```
rnd =
  FromCharacterCode @ 
    RandomChoice[Join @@ Range[{48, 97, 65}, {57, 122, 90}], #] &;

rnd[11]
```

> ```
> "liLC2RoA3cR"
> ```

Or five passwords at once:

```
rnd[{5, 11}]
```

> ```
> {"suPwm0c7FxS", "CV3khXaowWS", "Lac9z1IVCwc", "gptfkp2GMwH", "HDhRuFPLxte"}
> ```

Comment: Could you remember anyone? :)

Comment: @yode One? Yes.  A significant number? No.  My strategy is to use a password manager that effectively locks away a list of passwords behind a single one.  There is no way I could remember a large number of high quality passwords no matter the scheme used.

Answer (score 13):

Here's something which is nice and might be easy to remember:

```
StringJoin @@ RandomSample[#, Length@#] &@
 Flatten@{IntegerString@RandomInteger[{10, 999}],
   Capitalize /@ RandomWord[3],
   RandomSample[Characters@"!@_%$^=+*.", 2]
   }
```

Select examples:

```
"Tearless+PostdoctoralDragon=635" (*DEFINTIELY MY FAVORITE!!*)
"Workpiece.Monopolize908Moderate="
"Venereal854RebelliouslyProportionality%."
```

### EDIT

To increase the entropy, you may want to make spelling mistakes. Here's a great way to produce pronounceable non-words:

```
spoilWord[word_String] := 
 Transliterate@
  Transliterate[word, 
  RandomChoice@{"Hebrew", "Arabic", "Japanese", "Korean","Greek"}
 ]
```

Example:

```
spoilWord@RandomWord[]
(*"matelialismeu"*)
```

Comment: This is a really funny solution ... I like it very much.

Comment: To increase entropy, you can also just add one or two more all lowercase, space-separated words. "a thought that never changes remains a stupid lie" is a very secure password that's both easy to remember and type. (Okay, depends, if someone knows I'm using verses from lyrics of songs I can randomly recall that will probably reduce the search space significantly compared to "ten random words.")

Comment: I would personally get rid of the extra punctuation - it's more to remember for very little entropy gain.